# "Incluido usted" vs. "incluido a usted"

Tags: gramática

Hola otra vez ~ Quisiera preguntar por qué no es “incluido a usted”, sino “inculido usted”. - “[La actual estrategia no es efectiva y todos somos responsables de ello, incluido usted, señor Presidente.](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/CRE-6-2006-11-16-INT-4-166_ES.html?redirect)” ¡Muchísimas gracias por antemano! Saludos

Comment: Como dice @wimi, "usted" y "todos" son parte del sujeto de la oración, que no lleva preposición. "Incluido a usted" podría ocurrir en una oración de otro tipo, como por ejemplo: "Este problema nos afecta a todos, incluido a usted".

Comment: @pablodf76 Me parece que en tu oración quedaría mejor "inclusive a usted".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Usted" forma parte del **sujeto** de la oración, que es "todos":

- Todos, incluido usted, somos responsables de ello

(es decir, "usted también es responsable de ello"). El sujeto de una oración nunca lleva la preposición "a".

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar a la respuesta de wimi, que es muy buena, podríamos decir que el uso de "incluir" en la oración:

- Todos, incluido usted, somos responsables de ello.

es casi metalingüístico, y por eso no se usa "a" a pesar de que "usted" es una persona.

Un uso lingüístico de "incluir" sería, por ejemplo:

- En la declaración de responsabilidades lo han incluido **a usted**.

En la oración precedente, "incluir" es una acción.

En cambio, en la oración original "incluir" indica que entre los referentes del pronombre "todos" está incluido el referente del pronombre "usted". En este caso, "incluir" no es una acción sino que es una aclaración del orden de lo textual.

Otra posible explicación por el no uso de "a" es que "incluido" es un adjetivo:

- Todos, y usted está incluido, somos responsables de ello.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias a todos por sus explicaciones!